# Using """ text here"""" isn't printing items on a new line

Tags: python

I've tried to google an answer and I probably just don't know the right thing to look for, so I'm not finding anything. Sorry if this is a newbish question, I'm still fairly new to python. Thank you in advance for your help!

I'm defining a group of characters forming the words Thank You using """, but when I call it, it's not printing correctly. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
thankyou = """
  ______ _                   _ 
 (_) |  | |                 | | 
     |  | |    __    _  _   | |          __ 
     |  |/ \  /  |  / |/ |  |/_)  |   | /  \ |   | 
  (_/\_/|   |/\_/|_/  |  |_/| \_   \_/|/\__// \_/|_ 
                                     /| 
                                     \|
    
"""
```

How the code looks when it's called:
[image]
The code and how it's supposed to look
[image]

I expected the characters to print on a new line in the same way I added them. Instea, they're coming out jumbled. I've tried googling and didn't find anything. I've also tried putting it all on one line and using \n to break a new line, but that's also not working. Any advice would be appreciated!

thankyou = '\n  ______ _                   _ \n (*) |  | |                 | | \n     |  | |    __    _  _   | |          __ \n     |  |/ \  /  |  / |/ |  |/*)  |   | /  \ |   | \n  (*/_/|   |/_/|*/  |  |*/| _   _/|/_*// _/|_ \n                                    /| \n                                     |'

I also tried this:

```
thankyou = "  ______ _                   _ "\
           " (_) |  | |                 | | "\
           "     |  | |    __    _  _   | |          __ "\
           "     |  |/ \  /  |  / |/ |  |/_)  |   | /  \ |   | "\
           "  (_/\_/|   |/\_/|_/  |  |_/| \_   \_/|/\__// \_/|_ "\
           "                                     /| "\
           "                                     \|"\
```

edit:
–
jasonharper
YOUR COMMENT IS THE ONE THAT WORKED! THANK YOU!

Comment: Your code is working fine [in this demo](https://rextester.com/DJWPI55935).  The current output you are seeing is an artifact, and for whatever reason seems to not be printing newlines.

Comment: You're confusing the text representation of text in Python (something like `'line\nnext line'`) with what the text would look like when printed (something like `line` on the first line and `next line` on the next). Python represents line breaks in strings with `\n` (like most languages do) to avoid programmers having to deal with all kinds of control characters wreaking havoc on their editors - but if you print a `\n`, it just prints a new line.

Comment: You just echoed it in the interactive interpreter, you didn't actually `print` it. Try `print(thankyou)` to make it print the "human friendly" `str` form (echoing prints the "programmer friendly" `repr` form).

Comment: Simply typing the name of a variable in an interactive Python prompt will show you the `repr()` of that variable, as this will generally give you more details about the value - but it's not what you want here.  Try `print(thankyou)` instead to output the string itself.

Comment: It would _sure help_ if you showed us the actual code that is displaying the string...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing your window.

when the terminal is to small, it will word wrap and have the characters that don't fit on the next line, thus making your output all jumbled and weird.

Comment: This isn't the problem.  The problem is that they weren't using `print(thankyou)` -- they were just typing `thankyou` in an interactive interpreter.